# Styling ::tab of a QTabBar element results in style lose

Tags: qt, tabs, styling

In my application, I want to style the selected tab of a **QTabBar** element. What I style is only its **background-color**, but every time I change its **background-color** attribute, all the other styles are immediately lost.
At first I thought it was an issue only for **background-color**'s, but then trying more I noticed that even by changing the margins of the tabs, all the other styles are lost. The **background-color** of the other tabs is set to transparent, padding and borders lost too.

I think that the correct way for QT to behave, should be to leave untouched the attributes that I have not explicitly modified, but for such an obvious behaviour not to be implemented there have to be other reasons or I am missing something.

Is this an actual “bug” or is there something that I did not consider when trying to styling the tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue that you are running into is that once you alter the style of a GUI element, Qt can no longer draw it using your OS's native controls.

When you alter the style of any kind of native widget (tabs, combo boxes, etc), you should be prepared to take manual control of the style for every aspect of that widget since you are saying that you don't want it to look like a native widget anymore, and Qt has to use a different underlying painting system for rendering the widget.

Comment: I thought that QT always draw the same way, but using “CSS attributes” taken from the system. Well, it should be like that I guess.

Comment: Under the hood they use native API calls to make the widgets look as native as possible.

Comment: using “CSS attributes” taken from the system - what if system doesn't give any attributes - either it will draw it like it likes, or draw it completely on your own?

Comment: @j_kubik, I assumed that the QT framework should somehow be able to transform the system widget styles into the appropriate CSS attributes and include them into the cascading. But clearly now it seems that this doesn’t happen.

Answer (score 0):

@Mario and in addition to what Chris has already said about CSS styling overriding native OS styling:
Any application of CSS styling effectively calls

```
QWidget::setStyleSheet(const QString & styleSheet)
```

on the destination QWidget. This overwrites the previously set styleSheet css with a QString containing the new styleSheet; the widget then resets itself and parses the new sheet. Qt isn't smart enough to detect which parts of the widget styling that your new stylesheet will affect (and which it won't) and besides that, CSS doesn't support the toggling on and off of whether a particular attribute is applied. Qt would need to add the ability to remove as well as add CSS attributes for layering multiple stylesheets on one Widget to work (and you'd also presumably need a 'RemoveAllStyling()' function).